# WebGi teamplate of Palash Bansa, model and object in viewer?

Tags: html, frameworks, webgl, react-three-fiber

I read doc of this framework , but there're something I don't understand, after add 2 model, I check
'viewer-scene-children', they return Object3D type, but I cant change the position and camera of single element. Maybe they are in a same scene, how can I create a separate position-target for every element...

```
await manager.addFromPath("scene1.glb")
await manager.addFromPath("scene2.glb")
const firstModel = viewer.scene.children[0]
const secondModel = viewer.scene.children[1].position(-20, -20, -20)
firstModel.rotateX(Angle1)
secondModel.rotateX(Angle2)
```

Maybe they are in a same scene, how can I create a separate position-target for every element...